# How to allow Numeric Keypad on Regrex (Regular Expression)?

Tags: javascript, regex

My code:

```js
function IntegerOnly(el) {
  el.value = el.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="IntegerOnly(this)">
```

This code is allow to input only 0-9.

I input 0-9 from **Keyboard** is worked, but not work if I input 0-9 from **Numeric Keypad**.

https://jsfiddle.net/xzmsLhy4/

Comment: Works fine for me. Is your Numlock turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me.
You have to turn on your Num Lock in order to use your Numeric Keypad